# How do I only print every 5th line

Tags: python, printing, lines

I have a text file (`"name_data.txt"`) that has the following contents:

```
name: Kelo
family name: Lam
location: Asia
members: Kelo, Kiko, Jil

name: Miko
family name: Naiton
location: Japan
members: Miko,Kayati
```

The text file keeps going with the same pattern (name, family name, location, members)

I want to print out the first line and then print every 5th line so I would be printing only the line with "name" in the beginning.
I then want to have a list of the names

I want my output to be :

```
["Kelo","Miko"]
```

So far, I have gotten (although, it is wrong):

```
name_data= load_local_file('name_data.txt',ignore_header=False,delimiter='\t')


def __init __(name_reader): 

    names=list()  
    count=0  
    name_line=5  
    line_number=0  

    for name in name_data:

        if line_number<5:  

            line_number +=1  

        if line_number ==5: 

            names.append(line_number)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can identify every fifth line by comparing the `linenumber modulo 5` against a number. In your case this should be `0` because you want the first line and the 6th, the 11th, ... (note that python starts with index 0)

To get the line-numbers as well as the content you can iterate over the file with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Then to discard the `name:` part of the string and keep what comes after, you can use [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

A working implementation could look like this:

```
# Create an empty list for the names
names = []

# Opening the file with "with" makes sure it is automatically closed even
# if the program encounters an Exception.
with open('name_data.txt', 'r') as file:
    for lineno, line in enumerate(file):
        # The lineno modulo 5 is zero for the first line and every fifth line thereafter.
        if lineno % 5 == 0:
            # Make sure it really starts with "name"
            if not line.startswith('name'):
                raise ValueError('line did not start with "name".')
            # Split the line by the ":" and keep only what is coming after it.
            # Using `maxsplit=1` makes sure you don't run into trouble if the name 
            # contains ":" as well (may be unnecessary but better safe than sorry!)
            name = line.split(':', 1)[1]
            # Remove any remaining whitespaces around the name
            name = name.strip()
            # Save the name in the list of names
            names.append(name)

# print out the list of names
print(names)
```

Instead of enumerate you could also use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) with a step argument:

```
from itertools import islice

with open('name_data.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in islice(file, None, None, 5):
        ... # like above except for the "if lineno % 5 == 0:" line
```

---

Depending on your needs you might consider using the `re` module to completly parse the file:

```
import re
# The regular expression
group = re.compile(r"name: (.+)\nfamily name: (.+)\nlocation: (.+)\nmembers: (.+)\n", flags=re.MULTILINE)
with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    # Apply the regex to your file
    all_data = re.findall(group, file)
# To get the names you just need the first element in each group:
firstnames = [item[0] for item in all_data]
```

The `firstnames` will be `['Kelo', 'Miko']` for your example and similar if you use `[item[1] for item in all_data]` then you get the last names: `['Lam', 'Naiton']`. 
To successfully use a regular expression you must ensure it really matches your file layout otherwise you'll get wrong results.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do this would be as follows:

```
with open('name_data.txt', 'r') as file:

    index = 0
    for line in file:
        if index % 5 == 0:
            print(line.split()[1])
        index += 1
```

Comment: Hi tom_1230, thanks for your comment. I tried to print(line) and the output came back as a traceback:     return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)  ; do you know what that means?

Comment: The code works perfectly for me, perhaps the text file encoding is messed up. Create a new .txt file and copy the input you specified in your original question and see if that works.

Comment: I also updated the code in my answer, just realized you only wanted to print the names and not the whole line.

Comment: Note that `file.close()` is not necessary here. The `with` context manager does that for you.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this in one line with a list comprehension

```
c = open('test.txt', 'r').readlines()

# for every fifth line extract out name and store in list
a = [i.replace('name: ', '').replace('\n', '') for i in c[::5]]

print(a) # ['Kelo', 'Miko']
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `name_data` is a list of lines in the file, you can do

```
names = []
for i in range(1, len(name_data), 5):
    names.append(name_data[i].split(":")[1].strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

Having a `name_data.txt` file with data as follows:

`1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10`

Here's how you can print the first and every 5th line of it:

```
content = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('name_data.txt')]
names = []
limit = 4
fp = open("name_data.txt")
names.append(content[0])
for i, line in enumerate(fp):
    if i == limit:
        names.append(line)
        limit += 5
fp.close()
print(names)
```

Checkout http://shortcode.pro/code/read-txt-file-and-print-first-and-every-5th-line/

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions - Python's module for that is `re`.

Then with `name_data.txt` being:

```
name: Kelo
family name: Lam
location: Asia
members: Kelo, Kiko, Jil

name: Miko
family name: Naiton
location: Japan
members: Miko,Kayati
```

Getting the names is simple one-liner:

```
import re

def get_names():

    with open('name_data.txt', 'r') as f:
        print(re.findall(r'^name:\s*(\w+)', f.read(), flags=re.MULTILINE))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    get_names()
```

Note the multiline flag setting - when the setting is global, the regex would also match lines with `family name: ...`. 
See the regex in interactive mode [here](https://regex101.com/r/JHW84G/1).